# Can Kaa IoT platform provides predictive digital twin?

Tags: analytics, iot, kaa

I have been studying about kaa iot platform from couple of days. I have came across that it provides implementation of digital twin but i no where found that kaa only registers the devices data as digital twins or can produce statistical analysis for preventive maintenance.

Our application needs to perform predictive/statistical analysis on device data collected as digital twins to identify any failure cases.

Answer (score 3):

In short - yes, you can sure create a Predictive Digital Twin with Kaa.

If i've got you right, your devices are already connected to the cloud.

Here you can see Kaa Enterprise IoT Platform controlling the Digital Twin of the device. In this sample demo, our software collects and visualizes statistical data on a horizontal line chart.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iAuxaDalQYc

To perform advanced analytics on device data collected, you just have to choose your favorite analytics engine and connect it to Kaa (via open APIs) - our platform comes pre-integrated with Kafka, so this should be an easy ride.

Also, you can integrate Kaa with any modern DB you are using, and feed your structured or unstructured data to Kaa without any effort.

In case your devices are not yet connected to the cloud, our IoT engineers would be happy to help you produce smart products for mass market faster.

Has this been helpful to you?

I will be glad to share more information about Kaa and our expertise in similar use cases, you are welcome to contact me directly here or in Linkedin https://www.linkedin.com/in/aglivinska/

Answer (score -1):

I don't really know the KaaIoT plaform well enough to answer this directly, but there are alternatives as well.

You may want to try out https://www.bosch-iot-suite.com/analytics/ for free and see if this is what you are looking for.
The [tutorial](https://docs.bosch-iot-suite.com/analytics/useexplore/index.html#anchor22233) shows how to get started with anomaly detection.

There is an API to access your Digital Twin data. The technology behind that is the Eclipse Ditto open source project, but that does not contain any advanced analytics functionality when run on-premises.

*Disclaimer: I work for the vendor.*